# Using javers 3.0.0 and cannot get changes to work on H2 or SQLServer

Tags: javers

I have a simple test setup to create an entity (known to javers) within a Spring boot app, make a couple of changes with commits and then report back the changes.

I would expect this to work, but I always get back no changes.

I can get snapshots to work fine, but not changes on 3.0.0.

Anyone had similar experience?

Sample Code:

```
@Test
public void simpleTest() {
    System.out.println(javers.getTypeMapping(Bookmark.class).prettyPrint());

    Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
    bookmark.setName("new bookmark");
    bookmark = bookmarkService.saveBookmark(bookmark);
    javers.commit("creator", bookmark);

    bookmark.setName("updated bookmark");
    javers.commit("updater", bookmark);

    QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byInstance(bookmark);
    List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build());
    String changeLog = javers.processChangeList(changes, new SimpleTextChangeLog());
    System.out.println(changeLog);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
EntityType{
  baseType: class model.Bookmark
  typeName: model.Bookmark
  managedProperties:
    Field BigInteger id; //declared in Bookmark
    Field String name; //declared in Bookmark
  idProperty: id
}

main] o.javers.core.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder   : live graph assembled, object nodes: 1, entities: 1, valueObjects: 0
main] org.javers.core.Javers                   : Commit(id:1.2, snapshots:1, author:creator, changes - ValueChange:2 NewObject:1), done in 5 millis (factory:3, persist:2)
main] o.javers.core.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder   : live graph assembled, object nodes: 1, entities: 1, valueObjects: 0
main] o.j.c.j.t.commit.GlobalIdTypeAdapter     : deserializing {"entity":"model.Bookmark","cdoId":10002}
main] org.javers.core.Javers                   : Commit(id:2.2, snapshots:1, author:updater, changes - ValueChange:2 ObjectRemoved:1 NewObject:1), done in 10 millis (factory:7, persist:3)
main] o.j.c.j.t.commit.GlobalIdTypeAdapter     : deserializing {"entity":"model.Bookmark","cdoId":10002}
main] o.j.c.j.t.commit.GlobalIdTypeAdapter     : deserializing {"entity":"model.Bookmark","cdoId":10002}
```

The changes size is 0 and the output is blank. I've tried a few variations, but nothing seems to work. I even tried switching from SQLServer to H2 but got the same results.

Just wondering if I am mis-understanding the documentation or if it could be a bug in 3.0.0 running on Java 8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing my query allowed me to get back results:

```
QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byInstance(bookmark);
```

to

```
QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byInstance(bookmark).withNewObjectChanges();
```

this is because all of my objects were being marked with a type of "INITIAL" even after restarts. More investigation required as to why this is occurring, but for now, a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the Javers code, it seems they generate a shadowGraph of the snapshots, which is simply a set.

When checking to see if this object is an update or new item, it looks to see if it is in the shadowgraph by seeing if the new item is in the set.

Using the globalId's of the items in the set, they are compared.

However, my objects always have some strange information after the typename which causes them to never equate and such that a new object is always assumed.

screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by modifying Javers to use BigInteger as a well known type such that the cdoId is properly converted to a string value.

I've generated a pull request to finish this out:

https://github.com/javers/javers/pull/508

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger isn't mapped as Value but ValueObject. Your PR should solve the issue. Thanks for the contribution, we will release soon.